# Testing subscribe in service

Tags: angular, testing, service, jasmine

Help please test the service. I found a lot of information about testing, but not one did not help.

> admin.service.ts

```
  private bcUrl = 'http://30.30.0.101:8080';
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.cookieService.get('token')
    })
  };

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {
  }

  getUsers(page, lim): any {
    return this.http.get(`${this.bcUrl}/api/security/users?page=${page}&size=${lim}`, this.httpOptions)
      .subscribe(
        (data: DataInterface) => {
          this.users = data.content;
          this.st.totalElements = data.totalElements;
          this.st.totalPages = data.totalPages;
          this.dataSource = data.content;
        },
        error => {
          if (error.status === 404) {
            alert('Сторінка не знайдена');
          }
          if (error.status === 401) {
            alert('Немає прав доступу');
          }
        });
  }
```

This is part of the code. I would be very happy if you help test it. Or send to the desired resource.

Here is my test. I started writing it, but I don’t know where to go any further.

```
import {async, getTestBed, inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import {AdminService} from './admin.service';
import {HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {UserService} from '@app/core/user/user.service';
import {RequestMethod, ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';

describe('AdminService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [AdminService, CookieService, UserService]
    });
  });
  it('should be created', inject([AdminService], (service: AdminService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));


  it('should be getUsers', async(() => {
    const adminService: AdminService = getTestBed().get(AdminService);
mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
  expect(connection.request.method).toBe(RequestMethod.Delete);
  connection.mockRespond( new Response(new ResponseOptions()))
});

  }));


});
```

Comment: Can you refine your question to ask about a specific problem you're seeing with your code? It's currently too generic ('please test my code') - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this one

```
  it('should be getUsers', inject([AdminService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: AdminService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {

      service.getUsers(0, 1);
      backend.expectOne({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://30.30.0.101:8080/api/security/users?page=0&size=1'
      }).flush(mockUsers);
      expect(service.users).toBe(mockUsers.content);
    }));

      it('should not getUsers on error status: 404', inject([AdminService, HttpTestingController],
        (service: AdminService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
        service.getUsers(0, 1);

        backend.expectOne({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://30.30.0.101:8080/api/security/users?page=0&size=1'
        })
          .flush(null, { status: 404, statusText: 'Пользователи системы Not Found' });
          expect(service.users).toBeFalsy();
        }));

  it('should not getUsers on error status: 401', inject([AdminService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: AdminService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
      service.getUsers(0, 1);

      backend.expectOne({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://30.30.0.101:8080/api/security/users?page=0&size=1'
      })
        .flush(null, { status: 401, statusText: 'Unauthorized' });
      expect(service.users).toBeFalsy();
    }));
```